# Apache fast cgi mod_rewrite : no input file

Tags: mod-rewrite

- */index/* to */index.php*
- */index/hello* to */index.php/hello*

The site is use path_info, and the default rule not works:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$      $1.php/$2   [L]
```

I change to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)((/[^/]+)*)/?$ $1.php$2 [L]
```

That was strange

- */index/ to */index.php* works fine
- */index/hello* to */index.php/hello* not work

And it says **No input file specified.**

Php is run in **fast cgi** mode in Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

path_info differs on every server and combination of Webserver and PHP. Why not use GET variables to do the routing?

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)((/[^/]+)*)/?$ routing.php/?site=$1&module=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you,I finish that by using a routing php file